# Avoid duplicated operations in lambda functions

Tags: python, regex, lambda

I'm using a lambda function to extract the number in a string:

```
text = "some text with a number: 31"
get_number = lambda info,pattern: re.search('{}\s*(\d)'.format(pattern),info.lower()).group(1) if re.search('{}\s*(\d)'.format(pattern),info.lower()) else None
get_number(text,'number:')
```

How can I avoid to make this operation twice?:

```
re.search('{}\s*(\d)'.format(pattern),info.lower()
```

Comment: Write a regular function using `def` instead.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yeah, I realized using def will be better when I had to move the cursor to read the function. Still, I'm interested in the answer.

Comment: The answer is write a regular function using `def`.  There are things you can do in a `def` that you can't do in a `lambda`.  There is nothing you can do in a `lambda` that you can't do in a `def`.  If you can't do something with `lambda` and can do it with `def`, use `def` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `findall()` instead, it handles a no match *gracefully*. `or` is the only statement needed to satisfy the return conditions. The `None` is evaluated last, thus returned if an empty list is found (*implicit truthiness of literals like lists*).

```
>>> get_number = lambda info,pattern: re.findall('{}\s*(\d)'.format(pattern),info.lower()) or None
>>> print get_number(text, 'number:')
['3']
>>> print get_number(text, 'Hello World!')
>>>
```

That being said, I'd recommend defining a regular **named** function using `def` instead. You can extract more complex parts of this code to variables, leading to an easier to follow algorithm. Writing long anonymous function can lead to code smells. Something similar to below:

```
def get_number(source_text, pattern):
    regex = '{}\s*(\d)'.format(pattern)
    matches = re.findall(regex, source_text.lower())
    return matches or None
```

Answer (score 1):

This is super ugly, not going to lie, but it does work and avoids returning a match object if it's found, but does return None when it's not:

```
lambda info,pattern: max(re.findall('{}\s*(\d)'.format(pattern),info.lower()),[None],key=lambda x: x != [])[0]
```